# Why my keystonejs app has https though I didn't do anything?

Tags: ssl, https, keystonejs

I made a keystonejs app and published to heroku server.
However, I just figured out that it's on https layer even if I did nothing about any ssl. Also I did nothing on heroku side either.

I won't write down my url at this moment, but if necessary I will share it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are accessing your app via a URL that ends in herokuapp.com, so you can thank Heroku.  You are being covered by their SSL certificate, as it is their domain.  Once you add your own custom domain to access your app you will have to worry about SSL provisioning.  At that time, [this document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl) should be able to help.